# Why didn't Arrow (Oliver Queen) just become part of the League of Assassins?

Tags: character, arrowverse, arrow

I understand that "League of Assassins" are supposedly the bad guys and no matter their philosophy, it usually ends in destruction of lives. But hear me out.

Arrow was, in Ra's own words, "one of the greatest students he ever had" and with confidence, he was ready to pass down the throne and the privileges that come by it. Oliver of course, had a different set of philosophies not aligned with the League, hence ultimately chooses better off from it.

But isn't the philosophy of the League the philosophy of the one who is leading it? Ra's mentions as much. Imagine all that Arrow could've done with a league as capable and powerful as the Shadows. Even if he chooses not to make use of it, he could've simply disbanded the league to ensure it wouldn't fall to the wrong hands. I still feel, giving away the ring to Malcolm was a highly irrational and even a dangerous decision. Is there a good reason why he didn't become Demon Head?

Answer (score 2):

#### He did what was the right to do.

He was on a journey of becoming Green Arrow after previously being the ruthless killer Hood. So using the *League of Assassins* for his bidding would mean becoming Hood again, a ruthless vigilante, killing people because he can. But Oliver is becoming better than this and that's his character's progress.

> He could've simply disbanded.

Yes, but then he would free trained assassins and let them out into the open without anyone to guide them. Who will take care of them? How to make sure that nobody else will gather them and start it again?

So doing what is right was his way to deal with it.